# Is there a way to watch videos (for example on YouTube) faster?

Tags: video, speed, youtube

Is there a way to watch videos (for example on YouTube) faster?

I mean faster rate. I don't have problems with buffering etc., but I need to speed up videos :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Increase or Decrease the Playback Speed of YouTube Videos [HowTo]**

> **[Enounce MySpeed™ Plug-In for YouTube](http://secure.enounce.com/myspeed.php)** is a utility for Windows
>   XP and Vista, which after
>   installation, runs in your system
>   tray. Whenever you visit a YouTube
>   video page (in fact any page that
>   contains a flash video), it shows a
>   little slider using which you can
>   change the video playback speed.

[image]

> 1.0 is the normal playback speed. Set the slider to anything less than 1.0
>   and you can slow down the video.
>   Taking the slider above 1.0, increases
>   the speed of video playback. A very
>   good feature is that this utility
>   doesn’t distort the audio even at high
>   playback speeds. It eats less memory
>   (about 7 Mb) and will not hog your
>   system.
>
> **Required OS**
>
> Windows XP or Vista
>
> **Browser**
>
> Internet Explorer 6 or 7 or Firefox 2
>   or 3 (Google Chrome, Safari and Opera
>   works, but is experimental).
>
> **Flash Version**
>
> Flash 9 or 10.

**[Source](http://secure.enounce.com/myspeed.php)**

Answer (score 2):

Download the videos and watch them on your computer with [VLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player). To download them, there's plenty of Firefox addons, [this site](http://kickyoutube.com), kickyoutube.com or [this](http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/) piece of free and open source software. Personally I suggest *Kick YouTube* for the quickest and easiest downloading, and many formats that are easy to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [MySpeed](http://www.enounce.com/products) for PC?

You can also download the .flv file and play back in [VLC Media Player](http://www.geckoandfly.com/2008/09/04/fast-forward-downloaded-youtubes-flv-in-vlc-media-player/).